# How to login SQL Server 2014 remotely?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I want to connect to SQL Server remotely but I got the issues. 
I am trying to connect SQL Server 2012 from my PC (SQL Server 2014).

But I got a popup error message came while login :

> Microsoft SQL Server error 1326

Note: I added SQL port in Windows Firewall as well as I enabled TCP/IP protocol and allow remote access in my PC.

Now  what is the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to link servers? Or are you trying to connect to a server. If so what are you using to connect (custom app, SSMS, etc)?

Comment: Looking up the error message in my favorite search engine turned up several guides on how to solve this issue... have you done the same and followed the steps outlined in these links?